# iOS Safari clears form fields after pressing browser back button

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, http, ruby-on-rails-5, mobile-safari

I have a rails form, which upon submission takes you to a preview page. On the preview page, you can either submit after checking or you can go back to make changes. In a few browsers I've tested (Firefox on desktop and Chrome on Android) when you go back the form retains all the user's previously entered details (which is ideal).

However on a couple of iOS Safari browsers, I've tested, the form is completely cleared. Is there a reason or fix for this? You do actually see the user's input for a few seconds before it's cleared. I'm assuming this is the browser doing this.

---

I do have a vague notion of a workaround involving collecting parameters and pre-filling the form again through a custom in-page back-button, but I'd rather avoid it.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Wouldn't a better approach that doesn't rely on how browsers handle forms actually be to flag it in the database as a `draft:boolean` and then after creation `redirect_to` whatever path you want where the user can double check and edit the information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't going to be able to change Safari's behavior with Rails. If you saved the form data to a cookie/session you could check for that and reload it into the form, though.

> involving collecting parameters and pre-filling the form again through a custom in-page back-button

This is pretty trivial and easier for the user to understand.
`link_to 'Edit', new_THING_path(params)`

That will take the parameters they entered and send them back to the new page with those params.

Then, if there are params:
`@thing = Thing.new(params)`

This will set the form up with any passed in parameters, or a default object if there are not any parameters.

They can submit and edit the form multiple times until they get it correct.